# IronRuby / IronPython in the same project?

Tags: ironpython, ironruby

I've been trying to build and application that utilizes both IronRuby and IronPython, but I keep running into reference errors with the shared DLLs, specifically Microsoft.Scripting.dll. I've come to the conclusion that this is due to IP/IR using different versions.

My question is if there is a workaround *other* than recompiling IronPython/IronRuby? And if not, has anyone done this already and provided a quick download link?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe override the AssemblyResolve mechanism.  My biggest question is why BOTH?